# Extend Bootstrap CSS and add some more styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know how to extend a CSS and add some more properties to it.
For example:

```
<a title="Not clickable" class="pull-right btn"><span class="icon"></span></a>
```

The above line of code is using pull-right btn defined by bootstrap css.
Now, I dont want to modify that particular class because I am using it for many other controls.
I know that I can copy those properties and create another class and use it for this particular anchor tag.

Instead , is there any way in which I can extend that class and add few more properties in my `<style>` tag in my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can extend the class by mentioning the **class** or **id** of its **parent** **before** this **class**.

It will be applied to only those classes which will come under that parent class or id.It will have **high precedence.**

```
.<parentClass> .pull-right{
<css properties>
}
```

OR

```
#<parentId> .pull-right{
<css properties>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using inline css or adding a class or placing the class in other css or targeting the class using its parent class.

> Note: **!important** is used to override CSS

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
#some-div > .pull-right {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--Normal Button-->
<button class="btn btn-sm pull-right">Normal Button</button>
<!--End of Normal Button-->

<div class="clear"></div>

<!--Button with an extra class-->
<button class="btn btn-sm pull-right red">Button Red</button>
<!--End of Button with an extra class-->

<div class="clear"></div>

<!--Button with inline CSS-->
<button class="btn btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right:20px;float:left!important;">Normal Button with inline style</button>
<!--End of Button with inline CSS-->

<div class="clear"></div>

<!--Button inside some div -->
<div id="some-div">
  <button class="btn btn-sm pull-right">Normal Button inside div</button>
</div>
<!--End of Button inside some div-->
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/5f9mt7c2/)